# Interpolate `ident` in string literal in `macro_rules!`

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Is it possible to interpolate a `macro_rules!` variable, of type `ident`, into a string literal in a macro? In other words is it possible to "escape" the double quotes of the literal?

```rust
// `trace_macros!` requires nightly
#![feature(trace_macros)]
trace_macros!(true);

macro_rules! export_mod_if_feature {
    ($system:ident) => {
        #[cfg(target_os = "$system")] // <-- problem is here
        pub mod $system;
    };
}

export_mod_if_feature!(linux);

// ... should translate to:
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
pub mod linux;

// ... but instead it becomes:
#[cfg(target_os = "$system")]
pub mod linux;
```

I have tried using `#[cfg(target_os = stringify!($system))]` but the `cfg` requires an actual string literal after `target_os =`, not just a compile-time string.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `cfg` attribute expects a `literal` and the `pub mod` expects a `ident`, I think you can use two values as the input of your macro and match one as a `literal` metavariable and the other as a `ident` metavariable. This would be more flexible when the names of the feature and the module are different.

```
#![feature(trace_macros)]
trace_macros!(true);

macro_rules! export_mod_if_feature {
    ($system:literal, $module:ident) => {
        #[cfg(target_os = $system)]
        pub mod $module;
    };
}

export_mod_if_feature!("linux", linux);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=51b3dca517db796b44466300b8b8b3b4)

Comment: Is this AI-generated? because it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the [`stringify!(...)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html) macro does that, so also [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-convert-given-identifier-to-a-string-in-a-macro/42907).

Comment: The OP is aware and even posted that it doesn't work.