# Rust macro: generate if-else-if chain from variable number of inputs

Tags: rust, macros

I need a macro to prevent the need to write the following code for over a dozen powers of 2:

```rust
    pub(crate) fn calc(samples: &[f32]) -> Vec<Complex32> {
        let buffer = samples;
        let mut res = {
            if buffer.len() == 2 {
                let mut buffer: [_; 2] = buffer.try_into().unwrap();
                real::rfft_2(&mut buffer).to_vec()
            } else if buffer.len() == 4 {
                let mut buffer: [_; 4] = buffer.try_into().unwrap();
                real::rfft_4(&mut buffer).to_vec()
            /// ..
            } else if buffer.len() == 16384 {
                let mut buffer: [_; 16384] = buffer.try_into().unwrap();
                real::rfft_16384(&mut buffer).to_vec()
            } else {
                panic!(
                    "`microfft::real` only supports powers of 2 between 2 and 16384 for the amount of samples!"
                );
            }
```

However, I do not know how I can express this in a Rust macro definition. A macro would be invoked like this:
`generate_ifs!(buffer, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, ..., 16384)`

Probably, I need something like this:

```rust
macro_rules! generate_ifs {
    ($buffer:ident, $e:literal) => {
        {
            
        }
    };

    ($buffer:ident, $e:literal, $($es:literal),+) => {{
        generate_ifs! { $buffer:ident, $e }
        // do something special to generate "else if"
        generate_ifs! { $buffer:ident, $($es),+ }
    }};
}
```

But I can't see how this may work out in the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you are enumerating all the powers of 2 already, you can get a short solution by writing out the identifiers (`rfft_2`) of the functions too:

```rust
use microfft::{Complex32, real};

fn calc(samples: &[f32]) -> Vec<Complex32> {
    let mut buffer = samples.to_vec();

    macro_rules! gen_ifs {
        ($($size:literal => $func:ident),*) => {
            if false {
                unreachable!();
            }
            $(
                else if buffer.len() == $size {
                    real::$func(<&mut [_; $size]>::try_from(&mut buffer[..]).unwrap()).to_vec()
                }
            )*
            else {
                panic!();
            }
        };
    }

    gen_ifs!(2 => rfft_2, 4 => rfft_4, 8 => rfft_8)
}
```

I used a trick to get around the `if` vs `else if` problem by adding one `if false` branch at the start.

If you want to omit the function names in your macro invocation, it gets more difficult (if not impossible with `macro_rules!`), see for example this question: [Interpolate `ident` in string literal in `macro_rules!`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70374402/13679671)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Nicholas Bishop](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#rust-osdev_Lobby:gitter.im/$b82AlrF8JuuVaAPD7jwvadYBGvDRMQWL4a1C0rcrT44), I now have a solution using the [`paste` crate](https://crates.io/crates/paste) and a big `match`. The macro looks like this:

```rust
macro_rules! fft {
    ($buffer:expr, $( $i:literal ),*) => {
        match $buffer.len() {
            $(
                $i => {
                    let mut buffer: [_; $i] = $buffer.try_into().unwrap();
                    paste! (
                        real::[<rfft_$i>]
                    )(&mut buffer).to_vec()
                }
            )*
            _ => { unimplemented!("unexpected buffer len") }
        }
    };
}
```

I think, it is the neatest solution as it uses idiomatic Rust (just a plain match under the hood) and doesn't have the overhead of dynamic closure creation.

Answer (score -1):

You could work with a closure here. Create the closure in your macro invocation and immediately call it, returning its result. This allows you to rely on `return` in each `if`-statement, so you don't need an `else` block:

```
macro_rules! generate_ifs {
    ($buffer:ident, $($e:literal),+) => {
        {
           let anonymous_function = |buffer: &[f32]| -> Vec<num::complex::Complex32> {
                $(
                    if $buffer.len() == $e {
                        return buffer.iter().map(crate::as_complex).collect();
                    }
                )+

                panic!(
                    "`microfft::real` only supports powers of 2 between 2 and 16384 for the amount of samples!"
                );
            };

            anonymous_function(&$buffer)
        }
    };
}
```

You can find the full example [here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32d0d5f4b9c0d420e7d3282e490e4a49)